# memory/ ram app issues

Tags: android, memory, drawable

My app is a quiz that has an imageview that switches images (20) based on the question and each image is a 720*540 jpeg referenced from drawable resource. I also have a gallery of all the images that the user can scroll between. I have noticed that my app must be using alot of ram because after closing my app and using other apps on my phone my launcher, htc sense, almost always crashes. I don't have this issue if my app isnt installed or used. I know android kills low priority apps to free up ram so I am guessing that my app is using so much ram that my launcher keeps getting killed. Is there a way to clear the ram my app is using when it closes? or something I should be doing such as deleting the images from memory after they are used? I am rather new to android development and still learning everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely either a memory leak or that you are not properly handling your images. Please look into using a library like https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader which will ensure that your app is scaling down images for display